# Why its taking one extra input in java while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

that count is scanning 6 inputs and then giving the results of (sum of first 5 terms )/ 5. the 6th input is just extra , changes in the code so it can be avoided . I want it to only take 5 inputs at most. [setting value of count<4 isn't helpful].

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a_03 {
    ///Average of five numbers 
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0, count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter five integers: ");
        while (sc.hasNextInt() && count < 5) {
            int num = sc.nextInt();
            sum += num;
            count++;
        }
        double mean = sum / count;
        System.out.println(mean);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's taking one extra? [It only takes 5 here](https://ideone.com/T5OyWo).

Answer (score 0):

`sc.hasNextInt()` means "if the next word the user typed is an integer". The only way to determine this is to wait for the user to type another word.

Since you call it six times (along with five `sc.nextInt()`), the user will have to enter six values, where the last one is left in the buffer waiting for a `sc.nextInt()` to consume it.

The solution is not to check whether the user entered another integer if you don't plan to read it. You can do this by flipping the order in your `while` loop:

```
while(count<5 && sc.hasNextInt())
```

Since `a && b` only evaluates `b` if `a` is true (called "short circuiting"), it will stop when `count < 5` instead of first checking if the user entered another integer.

Comment: understanded sir ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I finally find the correct solution I don't why but evaluating the count condition before calling the hasNextInt() method on the Scanner instance solved the problem**

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
//change
while(sc.hasNextInt() && count<5){
//your code
}

//to
while(count<5 && sc.hasNextInt()){
//your code
}
```